# Seeking for a simple way to order my dfs to concatenate them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have about 12 dataframes that I am looking forward to concatenate  vertically , therefore I am using the following line of code:

```
all_data=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3....,df12],axis=0)
```

When printing `all_data` the error that is arising informs that

```
cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object
```

Thinking that the problem was that not all dfs where `type` `DataFrame` I checked out the types, and  all of them result to be :

```
class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'
```

After some hours 'I think' I found the source of error.

Though all dfs share the same column names they are not following the same order. For example:

```
list(df1.columns)=[title1,title2,title3]
```

while a different df is:

```
list(df3.columns)=[title2,title3,title1]
```

My question is:

Is there any way I can order the dfs columns of each dataframe so that I can concatenate them vertically without the need of treating each one individually?

I mean, could I order the columns using only a line of code?

Thank you in advance for reading my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this using list comprehension and `reindex_axis`:

```
pd.concat([d.reindex_axis(sorted(d.columns),axis=1) for d in [df1,df2,df3,....df12]])
```

Comment: returns that 'list' object has no attribute 'reindex_axis' I supposse it might be because df1,df2,ect are in reality dfs (as results of functions) stored in variables

Comment: I just spotted a typo.   Try it again.

Comment: Same error arising: 
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'reindex_axis'

Comment: Can you tell what is type(df1) ?

Comment: class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame' .

Comment: df2 is pandas DataFrame also?

Comment: pd.concat([d.reindex_axis(sorted(d.columns),axis=1) for d in [df1,df2]])  Does this work?

Comment: Okay check all you other dfX types

Comment: I will check every case individually THANK YOU